# The ravens of peacocks

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, knowledge, animals

My grandmother told my cousin, a military man, that all the greatest wisdom in life came from animals. At first we thought she was talking about /r/adviceanimals, but then he received the following mysterious missive in her will...

---

[image: Kangaroos]
[image: Various Cinematic Great Apes]
is the
[image: Insectoid Vampires]
of
[image: Frogs]
[image: Wombats]

Comment: is it a famous quote or something popular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pictures, in order, are:

> 1. A **herd**, **mob** or **troop** of kangaroos.  (Image is tagged "Kangaroos")
>  2. A **troop** or **shrewdness** of apes. (Image is tagged "Various Cinematic Great Apes")
>  3. A **scourge** of mosquitoes.  (Image is tagged "Insectoid Vampires")
>  4. An **army**, **colony** or **knot** of frogs.  (Image is tagged "Frogs")
>  5. A **wisdom** of wombats. (Image is tagged "Wombats")
>      <sub>*added **mob** for kangaroos (thanks @Dan Russell) and **colony**/**knot** for frogs*</sub>

Adding in the connecting words,

> (Herd/Mob/Troop) (troop/shrewdness) is the scourge of (army/colony/knot) wisdom.
>  Selecting the most sensible sounding set of words from the alternatives:
>
>  **Mob shrewdness is the scourge of army wisdom.**

I think this maybe is intended to mean, roughly,

> Mob mentality is the scourge of army intelligence.

Since your cousin is a military man, that sort of makes sense.

By the same principle, the title is

> **The *unkindness* of *ostentation*** - confirmed by OP.

Comment: Kangaroos can also apparently be a mob.  Title? A conspiracy/unkindness of ostentation/muster?

Comment: Sconibulus
Sconibulus
21:38
I actually had "Troop Shrewdness is the Scourge of Army Wisdom", which is a paraphrasing of something I read once which my brain has over the years paraphrased to "The Army Way and a clever recruit are sworn enemies" Close enough, it's English, so here's a check.

Answer (score 0):

Super partial(though it might help someone)

The images shown are-

> 1. Kangaroos/Flock
>  2. Planet of Apes/Apes **is the**
>  3. Disease/Malaria/Virus/Mosquitoes/Zika **of**
>  4. Baby Frogs/Toads
>  5. Australian Wombat

Comment: Those aren't baby frogs/toads. Tadpoles have tails and no legs. Those are very small adults.

Comment: Pic #1: A group of kangaroos are called a herd, or a troop. (Also, it's entirely plausible that those are grasshoppers.)   As long as I'm at it, the images in the post are tagged as follows:  "Kangaroos"; "Various Cinematic Great Apes"; "Insectoid Vampires"; "Frogs"; "Wombats".